Propery 'plugins' is not allowed in app.json, Expo
I'm getting a warning in my app.json Property 'plugins' is not allowed. Both documents listing these two plugins say to put it in the app.json file. I'm on expo 51 and react native 0.74.1. Any help would be greatly appreciated with this!
ExpoFonts
Expo Secure Store
 {
  "expo": {
    "name": "....",
    "slug": ".....",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon1.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "dark",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/FullLogo.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "buildNumber": "1",
      "bundleIdentifier": "..."
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "..."
      }
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    [
      "expo-font",
      {
        "fonts": [
          "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-Black.ttf",
          "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-Bold.ttf",
          "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-ExtraBold.ttf",
          "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-ExtraLight.ttf",
          "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-Light.ttf",
          "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-Medium.ttf",
          "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-Regular.ttf",
          "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-SemiBold.ttf",
          "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-Thin.ttf"
        ]
      },
      "expo-secure-store",
      {
        "faceIDPermission": "Allow $(Pumpzoid) to access your Face ID biometric data."
      }
    ]
  ]
}



You've misplaced plugins, it must be inside the "expo" object.
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-secure-store",
        {
          "faceIDPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your Face ID biometric data."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}

Your file should be this
 {
  "expo": {
    "name": "....",
    "slug": ".....",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon1.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "dark",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/FullLogo.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "buildNumber": "1",
      "bundleIdentifier": "..."
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "..."
      }
    },
 "plugins": [
        [
          "expo-font",
          {
            "fonts": [
              "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-Black.ttf",
              "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-Bold.ttf",
              "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-ExtraBold.ttf",
              "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-ExtraLight.ttf",
              "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-Light.ttf",
              "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-Medium.ttf",
              "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-Regular.ttf",
              "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-SemiBold.ttf",
              "assets/Fonts/RobotoSlab-Thin.ttf"
            ]
          },
          "expo-secure-store",
          {
            "faceIDPermission": "Allow $(Pumpzoid) to access your Face ID biometric data."
          }
        ]
      ]
  },
}


oh wow, I can't belive I overlooked that! Thank you a ton!
